# Get commit id of triggering pipeline from triggered pipeline build

Tags: azure-devops

I have pipeline A which triggers Pipeline B upon its successful build on Develop branch. I would like to get commit ID of Pipeline A builds which run on Develop Branch,  using below command but it does not give me exact id

```
 - bash: |
          COMMAND="$(echo '$(build.sourceversion)' | cut -c-7)"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$COMMAND"
        displayName: GetCommitID
```

could you please suggest if i am  missing something.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test,  although pipeline B is triggered by Pipeline A, Pipeline A cannot directly pass the commit id to pipeline B.

So the variable `build.sourceversion` will not show the correct Commit ID.

To solve this issue, you could add a powershell task to run the Rest Api to [Update the Pipeline B definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) in Pipeline A.

Here is an example:

Set a variable in Pipeline B

[image]

Pipeline A:

```
......
steps:
.....
- powershell: |
   $token = "PAT"
   
   $url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/definitions/{PipelineBDefinitionId}?api-version=6.0"
   
   $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
   
   
   
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
   
   
   $response.variables.test.value = "$(Build.SourceVersion)"
   
   echo $response.variables.test.value
   
   
   $updateurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/definitions/{PipelineBDefinitionId}?api-version=6.0"
   
   $json = @($response) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
   
   $updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateurl -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} 
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

Pipeline B : `$(test)` could show the full commit id.

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $COMMAND="$(echo '$(test)' | cut -c-7)"
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$COMMAND"
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- powershell: 'echo $(dockertag)'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use pipeline resources as the trigger you can also directly reference the commit id. See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pipeline-resource

```
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runID
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runURI
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceBranch
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceCommit
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceProvider
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedFor
resources.pipeline.<Alias>.requestedForID
```

Does that make sense?